# Nodal Analysis question that I am finding hard

Tags: circuits

[image]

I seem to be really struggling with this question. I see that there are two current sources in parallel. I combined them and got 2+0.2*Vx. And then, I tried to do voltage division but that obviously won't work as there are two unknowns.

I tried mesh analysis, but this made my i1 and i2 equal to each other which is a common error I seem to be experiencing. For reference, I labelled the meshes from left to right, left most one being i1 and the one on the right most side i3.

Answer (score 1):

2A are supplied by the source on the left, and 0.2\$V_x\$ goes through the source on the right. The rest must go through the resistors. Total current through the two resistors is $$2A - 0.2 V_x$$

Current in the 20Ω resistor is half of the current in 10Ω resitor (so a third of the total), so current in the 20Ω resistor is $$\frac{1}{3}(2A - 0.2 V_x)$$

\$V_x\$ is the current multiplied by 20Ω $$V_x = 20\Omega\cdot\frac{1}{3}(2A - 0.2 V_x)$$ I belive this can be solved for \$V_x\$.

Answer (score 0):

The terminals of the two current generators are at the same potential so they can slide freely towards each other. Furthermore, two current generators in parallel are equivalent to a single current generator whose value is the algebraic sum of the individual currents. Having said that, let's proceed with the calculation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calling the bottom node ground, we can write [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law) for the upper node, which is at potential \$V_x\$ (the only unknown):
$$\frac{V_x}{10} + \frac{V_x}{20} + 0.2V_x - 2=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers here that should guide you to what you need.  I want to point out something interesting about that dependent current source.

The dependent source's behavior is defined as 0.2Vx which in plain English is saying the current will be (1/5) the voltage across it.  A more general way to describe this is the current is directly proportional to the voltage across it.

Do you know of any other device who's current through it is directly proportional to the voltage across it?  How about putting in these terms: I= k*V, where I is current, V is voltage, and k is some constant of proportionality.

What if I rewrite it to I = (1/R)*V or I = V/R.  I and V are the same as before and "R" is this mystery constant.

Well that's just ohms law and R is of course resistance!  That dependent source is really a simple **resistor!!**

Your circuit simplifies to three resistors in parallel with a current source.